# OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab:443

Tags: git, curl, openssl, gitlab, php-curl

I'm having some issues with OpenSSL.
I'm facing an error:

```
OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab:443
```

first of all, everything was ok, I cloned a project, but when I run the project (the project was about accessing telegram bot API ), it shows me this error ( in PHP curl ), I searched and found some answers but none of them worked.
I'm using Psiphon as VPN and os is windows 10.
by the way, I cant disable VPN because of limitations and I don't have the VPN address and port.
Any solution?